# How to use Parallel.ForEach to loop into a DataGridViewRow

Tags: vb.net, parallel.foreach

I have a code below that loops thru each row in a datagridview which contains the server and the service name and uses the ServiceController reference to check the status of each service and return the value on the cell.

```
        For Each dgvrow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        myController = New ServiceController With {
        .MachineName = dgvrow.Cells(0).Value,
        .ServiceName = dgvrow.Cells(1).Value
        }
        dgvrow.Cells(2).Value = myController.Status.ToString
        Next
```

This works but it runs sequentially and it is taking time for each thread to finish before it goes to the next row so I want to run it on parallel.

I search here and stumbled upon Parallel.ForEach but I could not find the right code/combination to make this work.

My intitial attempt was

```
Parallel.ForEach(dgvrow as DataGridViewRow in DatagridView1.Rows
Sub(myServer)
    myController = New ServiceController With {
        .MachineName = dgvrow.Cells(0).Value,
        .ServiceName = dgvrow.Cells(1).Value
        }
        dgvrow.Cells(2).Value = myController.Status.ToString
End Sub
)
```

Which is definitely wrong, not sure what to put after the ForEach part

The expected result should look like below, I expect the Service Status Column to get filled up simultaneously.

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Server Name</th>
    <th>Service Name</th> 
    <th>Service Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Server 1</th>
    <th>Service 1</th> 
    <th>Not Running</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Server 2</th>
    <th>Service 2</th> 
    <th>Running</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Server 3</th>
    <th>Service 3</th> 
    <th>Not Running</th>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: A `DataGridView` is a UI element - you're not allowed to access it from any thread other than the UI. You can't use `Parallel.ForEach` on it. What are you trying to compute that makes you want to parallelize the computation?

Comment: Are you trying to update the statuses live?

Comment: Eventually, yes. I am trying to figure out how to get the status on parallel as this will run on list of more than 20 servers and it is taking sometime to check each one without doing parallel.

Comment: This sounds like it's a better job for Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataGridView` is a UI element - you're not allowed to access it from any thread other than the UI. You can't use `Parallel.ForEach` on it.

What you can do is extract the data as a non-UI object, work in parallel on that, and then assign the results back.

Try this:

```
'UI thread
Dim inputs = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(Function(dgvrow) New With _
{
    .MachineName = dgvrow.Cells(0).Value,
    .ServiceName = dgvrow.Cells(1).Value
}).ToArray()

'Parallel
Dim serviceControllers = inputs.AsParallel().Select(Function (x) New ServiceController With _
{
    .MachineName = x.MachineName,
    .ServiceName = x.ServiceName
}).ToArray()

'UI thread
For Each x In serviceControllers.Zip(DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow), Function (sc, dgvrow) New With { sc, dgvrow })
    x.dgvrow.Cells(2).Value = x.sc.Status.ToString
Next
```

---

Use this if the rows change order during the computation.

```
'UI thread
Dim inputs = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(Function(dgvrow) New With _
{
    .MachineName = dgvrow.Cells(0).Value,
    .ServiceName = dgvrow.Cells(1).Value,
    .dgvrow = dgvrow
}).ToArray()

'Parallel
Dim results = inputs.AsParallel().Select(Function (x) New With
{
    .sc = New ServiceController With _
    {
        .MachineName = x.MachineName,
        .ServiceName = x.ServiceName
    }, _
    .dgvrow = x.dgvrow
}).ToArray()

'UI thread
For Each x In results
    x.dgvrow.Cells(2).Value = x.sc.Status.ToString
Next
```

Keep in mind if rows are deleted during computation this will also fail.

---

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
'UI thread
Dim inputs = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Select(Function(dgvrow) New With _
{
    .MachineName = CType(dgvrow.Cells(0).Value, String),
    .ServiceName = CType(dgvrow.Cells(1).Value, String),
    .Row = dgvrow
}).ToArray()

'Rx query
Dim query = _
    From x In inputs.ToObservable()
    From s In Observable.Start(Function () FetchStatus(x.MachineName, x.ServiceName))
    Select New With
    {
        x.Row,
        .Status = s
    }

'Rx subscription
Dim subscription As IDisposable = _
    query _
        .ObserveOn(DataGridView1) _
        .Subscribe(Sub (x) x.Row.Cells(2).Value = x.Status)
```

This will update each row as quickly as the respond comes back - and it'll be processed in parallel.

I have assumed that you have a function with this signature: `Function FetchStatus(MachineName As String, ServiceName As String) As String`.

Comment: This seems to work but does the last part still shows the right status for the correct row? When I try to run the code with a list of 10 rows (servers), I still the the dgvrow.Cells(2).Value get populated sequentially from top to bottom. I expect all Cell(2) on each 10 rows to get a value simultaneously.

Comment: @Ruben_PH - So long as the order of the rows don't change during the computation.

Comment: @Ruben_PH - If there's any doubt about the rows changing order then just pass the actual row down in an anonymous object right through the calculations.

Comment: Is there a way to have the Cell(2) to get populated simultaneously? Running this on a list of like 10 servers, I see that Cell(2) still gets populated from top to bottom.

Comment: I added some more details on the question for the expected result

Comment: @Ruben_PH - No, you cannot access any element of a `DataGridView` from any thread other than the UI thread. So it must populate from top to bottom.